# PHP allow_url_include alternative for Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, xampp

I'm on a XAMPP for Windows 8.0.3 installation, developing a payments gateway plugin for my ecommerce site made via Wordpress. I moved some of my code to an includes directory, and then used `require_once plugins_url('/includes/class-wc-payment-gateway-elavon.php', __FILE__ );` to require the file from my includes directory.

In my website, I'm now receiving a fatal error, telling me "Failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found" on that line that I just mentioned. It also gives me a warning which states "require_once(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0", which to me means that the method to fix this error would be to change allow_url_include to yes in my php.ini file. To my understanding, it's bad practice to have allow_url_include set to YES in your php.ini file, as it poses security risks. Also, in Wordpress by default, the function "plugins_url" retrieves a URL within the plugins or mu-plugins directory, which is the directory where my plugin resides. Here is a reference to the function in the developer documentation for Wordpress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/

So, my questions are as follows. Why is my file failing to be retrieved with this method? Why would it mention that the https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration if I'm trying to access a file locally? Is there a better way to require this include than the method that I am using? I'm relatively new to PHP and coding as a whole, so I'd appreciate if you are verbose, or point me to other resources I may use to learn. Thank you for any responses or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your code doesn't work with `plugins_url` is because that returns a URL such as `https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/includes/class-wc-payment-gateway-elavon.php` which will be executed on the server as PHP and the *result* of that execution return, not the code itself.

My recommendation is in your main plugin entry file do something like this:

```php
define('MY_AWESOME_PLUGIN_PATH', __DIR__);
```

Replace that constant name as you see fit.

Then, whenever you need to include something you can just use:

```php
require_once MY_AWESOME_PLUGIN_PATH . '/includes/class-wc-payment-gateway-elavon.php';
```

In the longer run, if you have more classes you might want to explore using an autoloader instead.

Comment: Alternatively, OP can also use [plugin_dir_path()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/).

Comment: @cabrerahector, the thing that I don't like about that function is that it is literally just a wrapper around `trailingslashit( dirname( $file ) )`, so if you are deeper in your code you might get an incorrect file path. In our plugins we also define a constant in the root file that binds to `__FILE__` and that constant could actually be safely passed to that function, however.

Comment: I agree. I also use that approach whenever possible, Chris. It's just another alternative, hence why I didn't bother adding a new answer to this question (and why I upvoted yours).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Chris. I was looking more into what you mentioned here, though I'm not sure what I should be including as the string for "MY_AWESOME_PLUGIN_PATH". It seems like you are asking me to put the absolute path from the root of the filesystem, which would be C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\elavon-converge-payments, though I don't want to use that since I want this plugin to be portable to my live site, as well as potentially others that I make in the future.

Comment: Should I be using something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead to fulfill my desire of being portable?

Comment: I just realized that he meant the actual name for the constant, not the path itself, and then __DIR__ represents the directory that the main php file resides in. That makes it a LOT simpler than I was making it out to be. Thank you!

Comment: @EvanKirschenmann, I apologize for not being clear, but I’m also glad you were able to work it out!